# How do I prevent sbt from publishing pom.xml

Tags: scala, sbt

Originally asked by fommil on Gitter sbt/sbt channel:

> Does anybody know which task generates the pom file, e.g. in publish? I'd like to override it to do nothing.

Answer (score 6):

`makePom` task generates Maven `pom.xml` but you still need to tweak other things to not get included into published artifacts.

What you need is:

```scala
publishArtifact in makePom := false
```

See [Artifacts](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Artifacts.html) for more details.